# Eigen3 - accessing a (non contiguous) subset of vector elements

Tags: eigen

Suppose I have a VectorXf exampleVector with arbitrary float values and I want to select out some elements according to their values.

I can efficiently get a logical vector of true/false values according to my criterion
eg boolArray=exampleVector<1;

But now I want to make a new vector (of a smaller dimension) that contains only those elements that meet my criterion.

How can I do this efficiently in eigen3?

In R I could use reducedVector=exampleVector[boolArray]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the VectorXf stores its values in a continous memory range, you will have to copy out the values that you want. I am sure R does it the same way, so you won't loose efficiency. There is however no way that I know of to do it as conveniently as in R. So you will have to loop through and copy out the relevant values.